# Send Query to PHP Class and Return Array for HTML Option List

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am trying to send a query to a function in a PHP class and return the results as an array to fill an HTML option list.

I can send the query to the function but the while loop creates a new array for each value rather than an array of all values.

The code for my function is below

```
public function optionList($query) {

    $mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DB);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        error_log("Cannot connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
        return false;
    }
    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "{$query}");

    $rowArray = array();
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        $rowArray[] = $row;
    }
    return $rowArray;
}
```

The code to call the function and fill the option list from the returned results is below

```
<?php

   $register = new Option();
   $query = "SELECT country FROM countries";
   $option = $register->optionList($query);

   for ($i = 0; $i < count($option); $i++) {
       echo "<option value=" . $option['country'] . ">" . $option['country'] 
       . "</option>";
       }
?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: dump your `$row` here `$rowArray[] = $row;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
<?php

$register = new Option();
$query = "SELECT country FROM countries";
$option = $register->optionList($query);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($option); $i++) {
    echo "<option value=" . $option['country'] . ">" . $option['country'] 
    . "</option>";
    }
?>
```

try this

```
<?php

$register = new Option();
$query = "SELECT country FROM countries";
$option = $register->optionList($query);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($option); $i++) {
    echo "<option value=" . $option[$i]['country'] . ">" . $option[$i]['country'] 
    . "</option>";
    }
?>
```

You can even do this :

```
<?php

$register = new Option();
$query = "SELECT country FROM countries";
$option = $register->optionList($query);

foreach ($option as $o) {
    echo "<option>" . $o['country'] . "</option>";
    }
?>
```

Options without `value` use the content as a value.